# Need help recreating soulwax synth sound

Tags: synthesizer, sound-design

Can anyone give me some advice on how to recreate the synth from [this song? (starting at 1:38)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jb1jBn0uEOc#t=1m38s)
Specifically, I want to recreate it on a Yamaha Motif ES6 and I've tried different things but I just can't get anywhere close. I get that it's kind of a dubstep sound but there's more than just a wobble to it, right?

I'd appreciate any tips on how to get to a similar sound.

Comment: We have a ES6 in store, so I'll play around tomorrow with it and see if I can recreate this. I know Soulwax likes to use hardware synths, but I feel like this could more easily be created with a software synth

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a pretty standard dubstep bass lead.  Those are usually done by feeding a fundamental wave (usually a square wave) through a ring modulator, and playing with cutoff, resonance, and square wave duty cycle to make the swoopy noises.

Comment: I wouldn't call this dubstep or standard, but you are on the right track.

Comment: also, I think this sounds more like a sawtooth then a square

Comment: @TravisDtfsuCrum The song itself might not be dubstep but the sound being asked about is used heavily in that genre. Of course the sound itself predates dubstep quite a lot (my good old SIDstation came with several patches that sound like that).